# Class property as type of function

Tags: typescript, function, type-hinting

I want to assign a class property as a type of function. However, the function signature can vary wildly.

```
export class MyClass {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: AnotherClass;
    prop3: function;      // ?

    example1() {
        this.prop3 = () => 'string';
    }

    example2() {
        this.prop3 = (a, b, c) => new Promise(...);
    }

    example3() {
        this.prop3 = (a) => {
            prop: () => 'str'
        };
    }
}
```

What is the shortest way to define at `prop3`, that its value should be of type function? Most likely the property will be a fat arrow function so I don't think interfaces would work but perhaps a generic would?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generics won't help here. You can type it as simply `Function` (with the capital `F`), or as a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types) of the signatures you want to allow.

For instance, using `Function` (and `| undefined` since you don't have a constructor that definitely assigns a value to it — remove `| undefined` if you do in your real code, though):

```typescript
class MyClass {
    prop3: Function | undefined;

    example1() {
        this.prop3 = () => 'string';
    }

    example2() {
        this.prop3 = (a: string, b: number, c: Date) => new Promise(resolve => resolve(x));
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8BQ1vQA4CcB7XAZgC5oAxAVwDtgAXAS0NugB9o6ATAUwDMmtXtwDcGLDl4APMAFtcIXgEYAFAEp0knDgYALJhAB0BYiWgBeaBssA+aAHIIDfEIDmD8ToC+EnTPlFXgAmG0wdHX1DEyJSS2swCmdXWjcAGmgAIwpaajlM3nwM4AoAETAGXk0Le2EAd2gABSI5Q15VfF4IQhAAN147aE7uvvbpdXUvHF9vIA)

Or with just the two signatures you're assigning it:

```typescript
class MyClass {
    prop3: (() => string) | ((a: string, b: number, c: Date) => Promise<number>) | undefined;

    example1() {
        this.prop3 = () => 'string';
    }

    example2() {
        this.prop3 = (a: string, b: number, c: Date) => new Promise(resolve => resolve(42));
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8BQ1vQA4CcB7XAZgC5oAKSgSmgF4A+aCAF3wEsA7AczoB8qlMBTadeAGmgAjClwCuAW2kBTfFOAUAImFYq6TaAAUiijhBUAeBcrWMB0eVwAmKgGbcVzgNwYsOFQAPMEVcEBUARlp0fxwcVgALcwA6AmISBioDZgByMW4eHN84gF8-OKCQsJUAJmjMOLjElLTSTOFRdgKpWWgbVXVoTWgdPWy+lQB3Y1NzFUp8FQhCEAA3FQZmReW1+YAWGpoaYpwykqA)

Comment: When trying to use `Function | undefined` I get `Property '...' does not exist on type 'Function'`

Comment: @myol - What property are you trying to use when you get that? What code are you getting that error on?

Comment: in this case, the arrow function contains a property which is another arrow function

Comment: @myol - What does "contains a property" mean? Do you mean you have a property on the function object? (Unusual, but possible.) Or what? No code in your question shows using a property on `this.prop3`.

Comment: @myol - The code in the update is probably not what you meant. You have `this.prop3 = (a) => { prop: () => 'str' };` which creates a function that doesn't do anything. It has no return value, and its contents are a single labelled expression (not a property). Calling it has no effect.

Comment: Yes, let me think about this more. Thank you for the effort so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use '() => type' syntax to do this. You can defined the inputs in multiple different ways as well in this case it might be something like this

```
prop3: (a: string, b: number, c: T) => Promise<Y>
```

That will say that you can only assign functions to prop3 that have 3 arguments as inputs and returns a promise of type Y. Or you could do something like this

```
prop3: (...args: number[]) => Promise<T>
```

Where this says that prop3 can be a function that takes a variable amount of numbers and return a promise of type T. If you have something other types you need to cater for post them below, Typescripts type system is quite flexible in this regard.